# At the third stroke the time will be 13:14

Tags: time-words

Are you familiar with the phrase "At the third stroke the time will be.."?
I just don't get it.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's from a service present in many countries. It's a recorded message accessible through a toll-free number, which will give you the current time whenever you call. You hear that message, followed by three beeps, the "third stroke" is the third of those beeps. After it, the current time will match the announced one.

Reference: [Speaking Clock (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speaking_clock)

Comment: In the UK it is a premium rate number, not toll-free.